# Bootstrap 3 блока по ширине

Tags: bootstrap, html, выравнивание

Есть проект на **Bootstrap 3**. В нем есть глобальный блок `.container`, внутри этого контейнера нужно разместить 3 `div` по ширине так, чтобы слева у первого блока и справа у третьего не было отступов от края `.container` и между блоками была равномерная дистанция. Я пробовал поместить `.container-fluid` внутрь `.container`, но слева и справа все равно есть отступы и избавиться от них никак не могу:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4">Block 1</div>
   <div class="col-xs-4">Block 2</div>
   <div class="col-xs-4">Block 3</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте к контейнеру кастомный класс с padding-left и right 0

Comment: @Nilsan Пробовал, тогда 3 блока выравниваются по левому краю, а мне надо по-ширине.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPD. Чтобы распределить содержимое колонок по ширине, попробуйте [выравнивание внутри колонок](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting) и/или [просветы между колонками](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting).

А чтобы избавиться от отступов по бокам, достаточно убрать блок с `container-fluid`. Правильная структура в Бутстрапе:

- контейнер (`container` или `container-fluid`)
- внутри контейнера ряды (`row`)
- внутри рядов колонки (`col-...`)

Бутстрап задаёт колонкам паддинг `15px`, а рядам - отрицательный маржин `-15px`, и они компенсируют друг друга как раз для крайних колонок.

```css
.col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+1) { background-color: #cff; }
.col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+2) { background-color: #fcf; }
.col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+3) { background-color: #ffc; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <p class="text">Text</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">Block 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Block 2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Block 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант

```css
.mywrap{
  background-color: red;
}

.col-xs-4{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mywrap">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4">Block 1</div>
   <div class="col-xs-4">Block 2</div>
   <div class="col-xs-4">Block 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если нужно убрать отступы и у самих колонок то можно добавить еще так

```css
.col-xs-4:first-of-type{
  padding-left: 0;
}

.col-xs-4:last-of-type{
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: это не корректная разметка, т.к class col- должен быть помещен в контейнер с классом .row

Comment: согласен, поправил